# Отображение в combobox большого количества данных WPF MSSQL

Tags: c#, wpf, sql-server, entity-framework

Ситуация такая: к комбобоксу прикручиваются данные с БД MSSQL с использованием Entity Framework.
Сейчас данных относительно не так много (около 2 тыс строк), но при попытке открыть выпадающий список, приходится ждать 4-5 секунд, пока комбобокс отобразит данные. В комбобоксе работает поиск по тексту.

Данные прикручены к выпадающему списку таким образом:

```
myCB.ItemsSource = dB.Customers.OrderBy(i=>i.Name).ToList();
```

Не знаю, должно ли это было помочь (но не помогает:) в xaml прописаны свойства: `VirtualizingStackPanel.VirtualizationMode="Recycling" VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing="True"`

Может кто подскажет хотя бы подход, как быть в этом случае?
Есть мысль отображать данные частями, но как, пока без мыслей.

Comment: Не делайте запрос в базе к UI-потоке.

Comment: Вирутализация здесь не причем, можете вообще ее выпилить, хотя-бы до тех пор, пока не разберетесь с нормальной загрузкой данных. WPF изначально хорошо оптимизирован. 4-5 секунд - это точно не лаг интерфейса. https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/ef/core/miscellaneous/async#async-linq-operators

Comment: @aepot, прошу прощения, а что значит нормальная загрузка? если даже пошагать по коду, запрос и преобразование "dB.Customers.OrderBy(i=>i.Name).ToList()" выполняется 250 мс (если верить средствам диагностики vs). Проблема всплывает потом, конкретно при нажатии "открыть выпадающий список".

Comment: Попробуйте то же самое только со статичными данными без базы, например вручную заполните какой-нибудь List<string> данными и воткните в комбобокс. Тормозов не должно быть.

Comment: @VladD, немного вас не понял, возможно вы имели ввиду "не делать запрос к базе в UI потоке". Если не сложно, могли бы вы пояснить?

Comment: @Maks: да, имелось в виду «**в** UI-потоке». Или можно асинхронно, как указано в ответе.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ComboBox` использует по умолчнию обычную `StackPanel`. К ней не прикручиваются всякие примочки виртуализации.

Вот этой разметки достаточно, чтобы обеспечить эффективный рендер элементов комбобокса.

```xml
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
    <ComboBox.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <VirtualizingStackPanel/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ComboBox.ItemsPanel>
</ComboBox>
```

Атрибуты `VirtualizingStackPanel.VirtualizationMode` и `VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing` не нужны.

Еще рекомендую данные грузить из базы асинхронно.

```cs
Items = await dB.Customers.OrderBy(i => i.Name).ToListAsync();
```

А так же стоит реализовать `INotifyPropertyChanged` и работать через `Binding`, а не прямое присваивание `ItemsSource`.

Comment: супер!  <VirtualizingStackPanel/> помогло

Comment: вопрос по поводу асинхронной загрузки: vs ругается на метод "ToListAsync();". Пространство имен System.Data.Entity подключено. Интеллисенс его тоже не видит

Comment: @Maks `using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;` подключите.

Comment: а можно применить что-то подобное на <VirtualizingStackPanel/> только для DataGrid? Есть тоже небольшие задержки на отображение

Comment: @Maks да, там примерно так же оно работает. Только уже через атрибуты, как у вас в вопросе. Тема гуглится вполне себе нормально.